# Cardinality of dense subset of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, I want to show that any total orthonormal family in $H$ has the same cardinality as the minimum cardinality of a dense subset of $H$ but I am struggling to do this.